# Book involving a special ops guy coming to town to help his father, winds up fighting, and gaining abilities from, superpowered people

Tags: story-identification, novel, litrpg

I read this as a preview in the back of a book I read somewhere in 2022-2023 as an eBook, probably a Kindle book. As usual, part of the problem is narrowing this down among the wide number of books I've been reading. The protagonist is nominally unpowered, but the veteran of various combat/espionage overseas actions (I think maybe as a mercenary rather than as a soldier or government operative). His father contacted him prior to the start of the book, I think, via e-mail, asking him to come to town (a large city in the United States, maybe in California?) to help with something. When he arrives, he's greeted with a beautiful and very competent female assistant and there are obvious sparks flying. He winds up at a house in the suburbs, I think following a cryptic clue his father left in the message, and while there, finds a strange chamber and equipment, and then is found by a superhero who attacks him.

It's made pretty clear that an ordinary person has no real way to defend themselves against the average superpowered individual, but the protagonist, of course, is no ordinary person, and uses a combination of combat knowledge, good physical form, and dirty tricks to manage to get the superpowered individual into the chamber and slam the door. I think that the individual gets put into some sort of stasis and, much to his surprise, the protagonist gains some of the individual's abilities. I think he's informed of that via some sort of a computer interface, although I don't recall if it was on the equipment he found in the house, or something he found was getting broadcast to his head. He learns that the individual who attacked him is nominally a hero, and I think it was left ambiguous as to whether this was a case of mind control, corruption, or his father being the nefarious party (or believed to be so), and that's where the excerpt left off, indicating that he was going to continue trying to figure out why his father called him in, now apparently with the ability to steal superpowers (I don't believe he knew whether it was temporarily or permanently at the end of the excerpt), yet another thing that people may want to kill him for...

The book was written in English, American English specifically as best I can remember, and didn't seem badly written. Odds are decent that it was by the same author, or at least the same publisher, as whatever book I was reading. I'll keep poking around, but I wanted to post the question now, because this is the third or fourth time I've thought I ought to post it as a question, and forgot to actually get around to it the prior times. Especially given how many books I've recently read in the genre, it may be LitRPG, one of those stories where the protagonist, at the least, is aware of his stats, whether it's because the world is a game in some way, or because that's how he visualizes the knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted this to one of the litRPG groups on Facebook, and they identified it for me.

Dante King's [*Making Supers*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0B8XNR6BG)

> When people started to develop superpowers, the world changed forever. Me? I wasn't one of the lucky ones with powers. So I had to develop more mundane skills, skills which have taken me across the globe on dangerous missions.
>
> But there are some missions I’ve always had to refuse. I've never been able to take on a supe. They're just too powerful. They're gods, whereas I'm just a man, even with all my knowledge and training.
>
> All that changes after I discover my dad's secret research project. With this device, I can not only steal superpowers and take them for myself, but I can also choose to give them to other people.
>
> I can make supers.
>
> In a world ruled by egomaniacal supers, I'm about to upset the balance of power.

I reread the first chapter, and it is an absolute match.